# XML to JSON Parsing Error with Ansible using Parse_xml

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I was trying to parse a XML response to JSON using `parse_xml` from an AWS VPN output, but I'm getting the below error.
I am able to parse data with "vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration" but, it is when I apply the filter `parse_xml`, that the error arise.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration | parse_xml('aws_vpn_parser.yaml') }}): 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"}

The playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: '{{ PALO_HOST | default("localhost") }}'
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true

    collections:
         - paloaltonetworks.panos

    tasks:
         - name: load var
           include_vars: provider.yaml

         - name: load aws var
           include_vars: /etc/ansible/aws/vpn_facts.yaml

         - name: load variable dir
           include_vars:
                   dir: /etc/ansible/aws/vars/
         - name: aws_vpn connection info
           ec2_vpc_vpn_info:
               vpn_connection_ids: '{{ vpn_id }}'
               region: "{{ region }}"
               aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
               aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
           register: vpn_conn_facts
          
         - name: set_fact
           set_fact:
             parsed: "{{ vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration 
             | parse_xml('aws_vpn_parser.yaml') }}"

         - debug: 
             msg: '{{ parsed }}'
```

output of ***"vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration"***

```
 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<vpn_connection id=\"vpn-395e9883880\">\n  <customer_gateway_id>cgw-136da58e954a</customer_gateway_id>\n  <vpn_gateway_id>vgw-015c18a444e89</vpn_gateway_id>\n  <vpn_connection_type>ipsec.1</vpn_connection_type>\n  <vpn_connection_attributes>NoBGPVPNConnection</vpn_connection_attributes>\n  <ipsec_tunnel>\n    <customer_gateway>\n      <tunnel_outside_address>\n        <ip_address>131.226.22.251</ip_address>\n      </tunnel_outside_address>\n      <tunnel_inside_address>\n        <ip_address>169.254.254.58</ip_address>\n        <network_mask>255.255.255.252</network_mask>\n        <network_cidr>30</network_cidr>\n      </tunnel_inside_address>\n    </customer_gateway>\n    <vpn_gateway>\n      <tunnel_outside_address>\n        <ip_address>34.232.238.139</ip_address>\n      </tunnel_outside_address>\n      <tunnel_inside_address>\n        <ip_address>169.254.254.57</ip_address>\n        <network_mask>255.255.255.252</network_mask>\n        <network_cidr>30</network_cidr>\n      </tunnel_inside_address>\n    </vpn_gateway>\n    <ike>\n      <authentication_protocol>sha1</authentication_protocol>\n      <encryption_protocol>aes-128-cbc</encryption_protocol>\n      <lifetime>28800</lifetime>\n      <perfect_forward_secrecy>group2</perfect_forward_secrecy>\n      <mode>main</mode>\n      <pre_shared_key>JXzQgDDNG944e0nnh4w</pre_shared_key>\n    </ike>\n    <ipsec>\n      <protocol>esp</protocol>\n      <authentication_protocol>hmac-sha1-96</authentication_protocol>\n      <encryption_protocol>aes-128-cbc</encryption_protocol>\n      <lifetime>3600</lifetime>\n      <perfect_forward_secrecy>group2</perfect_forward_secrecy>\n      <mode>tunnel</mode>\n      <clear_df_bit>true</clear_df_bit>\n      <fragmentation_before_encryption>true</fragmentation_before_encryption>\n      <tcp_mss_adjustment>1379</tcp_mss_adjustment>\n      <dead_peer_detection>\n        <interval>10</interval>\n        <retries>3</retries>\n      </dead_peer_detection>\n    </ipsec>\n  </ipsec_tunnel>\n  <ipsec_tunnel>\n    <customer_gateway>\n      <tunnel_outside_address>\n        <ip_address>131.226.22.231</ip_address>\n      </tunnel_outside_address>\n      <tunnel_inside_address>\n        <ip_address>169.254.207.46</ip_address>\n        <network_mask>255.255.255.252</network_mask>\n        <network_cidr>30</network_cidr>\n      </tunnel_inside_address>\n    </customer_gateway>\n    <vpn_gateway>\n      <tunnel_outside_address>\n        <ip_address>54.225.7.92</ip_address>\n      </tunnel_outside_address>\n      <tunnel_inside_address>\n        <ip_address>169.254.207.45</ip_address>\n        <network_mask>255.255.255.252</network_mask>\n        <network_cidr>30</network_cidr>\n      </tunnel_inside_address>\n    </vpn_gateway>\n    <ike>\n      <authentication_protocol>sha1</authentication_protocol>\n      <encryption_protocol>aes-128-cbc</encryption_protocol>\n      <lifetime>28800</lifetime>\n      <perfect_forward_secrecy>group2</perfect_forward_secrecy>\n      <mode>main</mode>\n      <pre_shared_key>RDt7vieaxRkjUwaCJ8M8Lo.Qztdhhfdq</pre_shared_key>\n    </ike>\n    <ipsec>\n      <protocol>esp</protocol>\n      <authentication_protocol>hmac-sha1-96</authentication_protocol>\n      <encryption_protocol>aes-128-cbc</encryption_protocol>\n      <lifetime>3600</lifetime>\n      <perfect_forward_secrecy>group2</perfect_forward_secrecy>\n      <mode>tunnel</mode>\n      <clear_df_bit>true</clear_df_bit>\n      <fragmentation_before_encryption>true</fragmentation_before_encryption>\n      <tcp_mss_adjustment>1379</tcp_mss_adjustment>\n      <dead_peer_detection>\n        <interval>10</interval>\n        <retries>3</retries>\n      </dead_peer_detection>\n    </ipsec>\n  </ipsec_tunnel>\n</vpn_connection>"
```

Comment: Could you either share the `debug` result of `vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections` or the result of `- debug: var=vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections|type_debug`?

Comment: added it below code..

Comment: Throwing the `set_fact` lines in my IDE raises a YAML syntax error already, you should indent the line with `parse_xml` one level deeper if you want it to relate to your `parsed` fact.

Comment: not sure if this is proper way to define indentation:

 name: set_fact
           set_fact:
             parsed: "{{ vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration |  parse_xml('aws_vpn_parser.yml', indent=2) }}"

i'm getting below error with that: 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '}', expected ')'. String: {{ vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration | to_yaml(indent=2, width=2) | parse_xml('aws_vpn_parser.yml'}}"}

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis for your filter `parse_xml`

Comment: i'm not seeing i'm missing parenthesis here...can you please post corrected line for me ?


parsed: "{{ vpn_conn_facts.vpn_connections[0].customer_gateway_configuration | parse_xml('aws_vpn_parser.yml', indent=2) }}

Comment: since i figured out something was wrong with xml,, when i removed "\" in first prolong line , looks like it gets me valid xml file in validator, however in order to parse into json i need to remove it "\" using regex from output but not able to figure out what could be regex exp used...

i used "\\" to replace it '' but doesn't help me to remove '\' from xml...